# UIScrollView for image pages not scrolling to next page

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a `UIImageView` that contains four `ImageView` as subviews. Each `ImageView` acts as a page that the user can scroll forward and go to the next page (image). However, i am unable to achieve this scrolling to next page. It only shows the first image. Here is my implementation

**TutorialViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TutorialViewController : UIViewController{   
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *tutorialScrollView;

@end
```

**TutorialViewController.m**

```
#import "TutorialViewController.h"

@interface TutorialViewController () <UIScrollViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation TutorialViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tutorialScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    self.tutorialScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.tutorialScrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    self.tutorialScrollView.delegate = self;

}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

    UIImageView *page1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,screenWidth,screenHeight)];

    page1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tutorial1.png"];

    UIImageView *page2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(screenWidth * 2,0,screenWidth,screenHeight)];
    page2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tutorial2.png"];


    UIImageView *page3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(screenWidth * 3,0,screenWidth,                                                        screenHeight)];
    page3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tutorial3.png"];


    UIImageView *page4 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(screenWidth * 4,0,screenWidth,                                                                         screenHeight)];
    page4.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tutorial4.png"];

    [self.tutorialScrollView addSubview:page1];
    [self.tutorialScrollView addSubview:page2];
    [self.tutorialScrollView addSubview:page3];
    [self.tutorialScrollView addSubview:page4];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set `contentSize` for `UIScrollView`:

```
[self.tutorialScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(screenWidth*numOfPages, screenHeight)];
```

Comment: this helps to scroll but kind of creates 5 pages. My page 2 is now empty and i cannot go to page 5 (image 4)

Comment: @stud91 the page2's x offset should be `* 1`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the `ContentSize` of the `scrollView`.

```
self.tutorialScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(imageView.frame.size.width * numberOfImages, self.tutorialScrollView.frame.size.height);
```

This will scroll your `scrollView` in horizontal direction.